# Output string with decimal format limited to 2 dp

Tags: android, format, decimal

Stuck on this which im sure there is an easy solution to, just cannot work it out!!

I have tried decmialformat, numberformat, string.format() etc and nothing works. .

code below, i want to calculation to just show the output limited to 2 decimal places.  Have spent the last 2 hours trying various methods all of which causes the app to crash when run...

```
    Output = (Output1 / (1 -(Output2/100)))

    String OutputString = String.valueOf(Output);

    Num.setText(OutputString);
```

Comment: what type are your various `Output` variables (int, long, float, double)?

Comment: should have stated that it has been declared as a double earlier in the code.  BUt all solved now thank you!

Comment: @user1150531 did you tried with my answer before? I dont seems any difference from the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
double Output = (Output1 / (1 -(Output2/100d)))
Num.setText(String.format("%.2f",Output));
```

Hope this solves your problem.
Best regards

Comment: Legendary, thank you so mch for this, was about to give up!  just a question - what does the d after 100 do?

Comment: It indicates that 100 is a double, just to force it to use only doubles while calculating :)
I'm very glad this helped you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String OutputString = String.format("%.2f", Output);

Num.setText(OutputString);
```

`String.format()` to make sure you only get 2 decimal places in your output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Limit the number of Digits before and after the 'decimal_point' then you can use my solution.

```
private class DecimalNumberFormatTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
    int pos;
    int digitsBeforeDecimal = 6;
    int digitsAfterDecimal = 2;
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if(s.length() > 2)
            pos = start;
        else {
            pos = start + 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        mEdittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String text = s.toString();
        if(text!= null && !text.equals("")){
            if(!text.contains("$")){ //if it does not contains $
                text = "$"+text;
            } else {
                if (text.indexOf("$") > 0) { //user entered value before $
                    text = s.delete(0, text.indexOf("$")).toString();
                }else {
                    if(!text.contains(".")){ // not a fractional value
                        if(text.length() > digitsBeforeDecimal+1) { //cannot be more than 6 digits
                            text = s.delete(pos, pos+1).toString();
                        }
                    } else { //a fractional value
                        if(text.indexOf(".") - text.indexOf("$") > digitsBeforeDecimal+1){ //non fractional part cannot be more than 6
                            text = s.delete(pos,pos+1).toString();
                        }
                        if((text.length() - text.indexOf(".")) > digitsAfterDecimal+1) { //fractinal part cannot be more than 2 digits
                            text = s.delete(text.indexOf(".") + 2, text.length() - 1).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mEdittext.setText(text);
        mEdittext.setSelection(pos);
        mEdittext.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}

mEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new DecimalNumberFormatTextWatcher());
```

This also adds a currency sign as soon as the user types the value.

HOPE THIS HELPS ANYONE.